# How to change all hidden values to false in each state object?

Tags: redux

I am a little bit stumped on completing this without my solution looking hacky. Any recommendations? Is this easier to do in the reducer or should I keep this strictly in the action?

Surely this is easier than what I am attempting.

```
const initialState = {
  unlockWebsite: {
    hidden: false,
    state: 'accepted',
    completedCount: 60,
    completedIds: ['priceYourHome', 'websiteInformation'],
    totalTasks: 6,
  },
  prepareHome: {
    hidden: true,
    state: 'default',
    completedCount: 0,
    completedIds: [],
    totalTasks: 6,
  },
  findingBuyers: {
    hidden: true,
    state: 'default',
    completedCount: 0,
    completedIds: [],
    totalTasks: 6,
  },
  negotiateOffers: {
    hidden: true,
    state: 'default',
    completedCount: 0,
    completedIds: [],
    totalTasks: 6,
  },
  closeHome: {
    hidden: true,
    state: 'default',
    completedCount: 0,
    completedIds: [],
    totalTasks: 6,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Take an example where the initial state is

```
const initState = {"a":{no_change:"hi",change:"ha"},"b":{no_change:"hi",change:"ha"},"c":{no_change:"hi",change:"ha"}}
```

Say we want to update all of the `change` properties in all of `a`, `b` and `c` from "ha" to something else.

I can just create an action `type` in my `reducer` called `CHANGE_TO_FALSE`.

```
case 'CHANGE_TO_FALSE':
  const falsifier = Object.keys(state).map((key,index) =>({[key]:{...state[key],change:"hoo"}}))
  return Object.assign({}, ...falsifier )
```

Now, instead of "ha", the `change` property will hold "hoo".

State after change:

```
{"a":{"no_change":"hi","change":"hoo"},"b":{"no_change":"hi","change":"hoo"},"c":{"no_change":"hi","change":"hoo"}}
```

I'm not sure there's a simpler way to achieve this. This looks clean to me.

Comment: Love the solution! To clarify, is it okay to use .map, Object.assign within the reducer or should that be an action?

Comment: I think its compact enough to be used in the reducer itself in this case

Comment: @NickMassie If your state has only 5 sub-states as in your original snippet, it's even legitimate to just set all of those `hidden` properties to `false` via the manual, dumb way. Only if it really needs to be dynamic (as in if you change the shape of the state the falsification should still work the same) or if there are like 20 sub states you should think about automating it. 5 lines that each set the same property to true or false are explicit and readable. We tend to add complexity too early because it seems smart and elegant.